# How to compare two database Teradata and BigQuery tables

Tags: database, google-bigquery, teradata, datagrip

We have 2 database - Teradata and BigQuery. 
We need to compare data from all tables in Teradata to BigQuery 
Due to large number of tables and volumes of data, its not possible to extract data and perform diff operation. 
There are tools available like Jetbrains DataGrip which can help connect to teradata via JDBC (in absence of db connector). and the same for Big Query via simba driver and OAUTH connectivity. But these are still very time consuming activity. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/quick-start/ 
https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/07/10/using-bigquery-from-intellij-based-ide/ 
Is there any other less expensive option available for comparing two databases ?

Comment: In DataGrip 2021.1 connecting to Teradata is easier, the driver is already bundled there. And yes, Compare Data feature is database agnostic. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/executing.html#compare

Answer (score 0):

How about making a copy of Teradata-DB in BQ and compare both of them as follow:
https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-table-comparison-cea802a3c64d

Comment: Making copy of Teradata DB via exporting files is not feasible due to large volume of data.
Is there any other option to create Teradata-DB in BQ ?

Comment: You can just migrate your Teradata DB into BQ.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/teradata-migration .

Comment: Actually this requirement came after the migration process to verify if migration is successfully completed or any data truncation/duplication/deletion happened during the process

Answer (score 0):

Provided content of source (Teradata) DB have not changed since the migration, the common way to quickly verify the two tables are identical is to compute some hash of each table in source and destination.

You would need some fingerprint or hash function that produces the same results in both systems. I think MD5 and SHA1 (available as extensions for Teradata) are good options, but you need to validate they produce identical values for each type, which might be tricky for some types like floating point.

Thus, for each row I would compute something along the lines of
`SHA1(CONCAT(string_col1, "**", CAST(int_col2 AS STRING), "**", string_col3))`
and then aggregate it using `BIT_XOR` to get a single value for the table, which does not depend on the order of the rows. Since all computations are done by the DBMS and data does not leave it, the computations should be relatively fast.

I would do something like the following for each table

- Compare COUNT(*) to make sure we have same number of rows
- Compute for both databases the single fingerprint as described above.
- If the two fingerprints match, the tables are likely identical.
- If counts or fingerprints don't match, go slow route and find mismatch by downloading data.